# Python3.0 - tokenize and untokenize

Tags: python, python-3.x, tokenize, lexical-analysis

I am using something similar to the following simplified script to parse snippets of python from a larger file:

```
import io
import tokenize

src = 'foo="bar"'
src = bytes(src.encode())
src = io.BytesIO(src)

src = list(tokenize.tokenize(src.readline))

for tok in src:
  print(tok)

src = tokenize.untokenize(src)
```

Although the code is not the same in python2.x, it uses the same idiom and works just fine.  However, running the above snippet using python3.0, I get this output:

```
(57, 'utf-8', (0, 0), (0, 0), '')
(1, 'foo', (1, 0), (1, 3), 'foo="bar"')
(53, '=', (1, 3), (1, 4), 'foo="bar"')
(3, '"bar"', (1, 4), (1, 9), 'foo="bar"')
(0, '', (2, 0), (2, 0), '')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q.py", line 13, in <module>
    src = tokenize.untokenize(src)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.0/tokenize.py", line 236, in untokenize
    out = ut.untokenize(iterable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.0/tokenize.py", line 165, in untokenize
    self.add_whitespace(start)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.0/tokenize.py", line 151, in add_whitespace
    assert row <= self.prev_row
AssertionError
```

I have searched for references to this error and its causes, but have been unable to find any.  What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

#### [edit]

After [partisann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54982/partisann)'s observation that appending a newline to the source causes the error to go away, I started messing with the list I was untokenizing.  It seems that the `EOF` token causes an error if not immediately preceded by a newline so removing it gets rid of the error.  The following script runs without error:

```
import io
import tokenize

src = 'foo="bar"'
src = bytes(src.encode())
src = io.BytesIO(src)

src = list(tokenize.tokenize(src.readline))

for tok in src:
  print(tok)

src = tokenize.untokenize(src[:-1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
src = 'foo="bar"\n'
```

You forgot newline.

Comment: Nice!  Do you know why this is?  It seems as though it should work either way, at least it does in python2.x.

Comment: I don't see why that would matter?

Comment: Seems like you should file a bug against Python.  The newline does seem unnecessary.

Comment: It does seem like a bug. Tbh, I just guessed it since it's quite common error with C compilers.

Answer (score 0):

If you limit the input to `untokenize` to the first 2 items of the tokens, it seems to work.

```
import io
import tokenize

src = 'foo="bar"'
src = bytes(src.encode())
src = io.BytesIO(src)

src = list(tokenize.tokenize(src.readline))

for tok in src:
  print(tok)

src = [t[:2] for t in src]
src = tokenize.untokenize(src)
```