# Rejoin sentence like original after tokenizing with nltk word_tokenize

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

If I split a sentence with `nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize()` then rejoin with `' '.join()` it won't be exactly like the original because words with punctuation inside them get split into separate tokens.

How can I programmatically rejoin like it was before?

```
from nltk import word_tokenize

sentence = "Story: I wish my dog's hair was fluffier, and he ate better"
print(sentence)
=> Story: I wish my dog's hair was fluffier, and he ate better

tokens = word_tokenize(sentence)
print(tokens)
=> ['Story', ':', 'I', 'wish', 'my', 'dog', "'s", 'hair', 'was', 'fluffier', ',', 'and', 'he', 'ate', 'better']

sentence = ' '.join(tokens)
print(sentence)
=> Story : I wish my dog 's hair was fluffier , and he ate better
```

Note the `:` and `'s` are different than the original.

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41305584/10034612). You can use [MosesDetokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/moses.html) as your solution.

Just remember download the sub package of nltk first: `nltk.download('perluniprops')`

```py
>>>import nltk
>>>sentence = "Story: I wish my dog's hair was fluffier, and he ate better"
>>>tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>>tokens
['Story', ':', 'I', 'wish', 'my', 'dog', "'s", 'hair', 'was', 'fluffier', ',', 'and', 'he', 'ate', 'better']
>>>from nltk.tokenize.moses import MosesDetokenizer
>>>detokens = MosesDetokenizer().detokenize(tokens, return_str=True)
>>>detokens
"Story: I wish my dog's hair was fluffier, and he ate better"
```

Answer (score 0):

After joining u can use replace function

```
 sentence.replace(" '","'").replace(" : ",': ')
 #o/p 
 Story: I wish my dog's hair was fluffier , and he ate better
```